# jQuery - how to get the value of an input of type submit when ajaxifying a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

Suppose I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><!-- Insert your title here --></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#form1').submit(function(){

                // Let's see the values
                alert($(this).serialize());

                $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data){

                    // Do something on callback

                });

                return false;
            })
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://example.com/bla" method="POST" id="form1">
        <input type="hidden" name="ipt1" value="1"/>
        <input type="submit" name="sbt" value="2"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I serialize the form's values the value of the input type submit clicked is not there. How do I handle this kind of situation when ajaxifying my forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In non-ajax forms the value of the submit button is only sent with the form, if it is clicked. So if you want to mimic this behaviour with ajax you have to do it something like this:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
    var data = $("#my_form").serialize();
    data += data.length ? "&" : ""; // check if empty
    data += escape($(this).attr("name"))+"="+escape($(this).val());
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

This appends the serialized data of the submit button to the serialized form data.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I have lots of inputs of type submit on my form.

Comment: You mean, the code I wrote is for one submit button only? It could be extended for more.

Comment: Yes, I've put a class on all the inputs that matter to identify them. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. the `.serialize()` method does not serialize inputs of type `submit`.

Unfortunately the way you have it you would not be able to access the source of the event. Your best bet is to wire all the submits, and then append the source data like this:

```
$('input:submit').bind('click', function(){    

var data = $("#form1").serialize();
data += "&"+escape($(this).attr("name"))+"="+escape($(this).val());

alert(data);
$.post($('#form1').attr('action'), data, function(data) {
//do something
});

return false;
});
```

Comment: Is there a better approach to do this than handling all clicks on all inputs of type submit to append their values to the form's?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following solution:

```
<input type="radio" name="action" value="action_1" style="display:none"></input>
<button type="submit" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true" >Do Action 1</button>
```

You repeat this for any number of choices (name, value), and the form is submitted as soon as you choose one.
Make sure the page is reloaded after use.